# How to get depth of objects from Disparity Map?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, stereo-3d

I have a stereo camera setup and I am trying to generate a 3d reconstruction of the scene. I am able to obtain the disparity map from the images. After getting the disparity map, I am unable to understand how to get the scene. I am following [this](http://in.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/3-d-point-cloud-registration-and-stitching.html) tutorial given by MATLAB. Can anyone please help me with it?
I have uploaded all my files [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/5u7wvxx5eyicily/AADJgKcYHtinZ95e5-1RvR9_a?dl=0).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Typically, the depth value is on the Z coordinate. From this disparity map, and taking in consideration the tutorial link you provided, in order to get the objects depth, you just need to know their 3D position. Once you know the `actual 3D (X,Y,Z)`, you just need to look at the Z coordinate.

Tutorial Section - `Stitch a Sequence of Point Clouds`

```
hScatter.ZData = ptCloudScene.Location(:,3);
```

Comment: So this depth I obtain is the distance between the camera and the object the cameras see right? Is there a way to make it display on the image?

Comment: Exactly. Display the depth value on the image?

Comment: Yes. Like markers on the image. My disparity map is Left to Right, so I am thinking, I can maybe choose a few keypoints on the Left image and display the depth to these points on the image.

I had tried displaying the pointCloud itself, but I was unable to display it inside the GUI I have designed. Since I cant show the depth in 3D now, I figured I will do it in 2D.

Comment: Check this - http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/84051-how-to-print-output-in-gui

Comment: The question is to how to get these 3D points , not where the depth is stored in a 3D array. The tutorial provided is also misleading because the 3D there is already obtained with a Kinect device